# Search API with Panels in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, panels, search

I want to create a search that is able to index panels. The content in my Drupal system is mainly located in Panels (which contain Blocks with the content).

I installed Search API along with Fuzzy Search and i only get results for "normal" nodes/pages, but none for my Panels. Is there any way to add Panels to the search index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer: [Page manager search](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager_search). It works with the Search API module. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... adds the ability for Page manager pages to be searchable via the Drupal core Search module or the Search API module.
>
> Support for:
>
> - Drupal core Search module.
> - Search API module (via the Entity API module)

Note: this is a new module.